# React-router v4 showing multiple routes at once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am having an issue where my routing using react-router-dom is showing all routes at once.  So when I render my App component and the start that contains the Routing, I am seeing the pages for each route on top of each other.  So it looks like this:

[image]

Sooo to begin how this is all kicking off, this is my index.jsx that is rendering the App component on the page:

```
// Dependencies
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

// Components
import App from './components/app.jsx';

// Styles
import './index.scss';

const container = document.getElementById('main');

ReactDOM.render(<App />, container);
```

In my App Component, the routing is set up as so:

```
// Dependencies
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Match, Miss } from 'react-router-dom';

// Components
import Login from './pages/login/login.jsx';
import Home from './pages/home/home.jsx';

// Styles
import './app.scss';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
          <Route exact pattern='/' component={Login}/>
          <Route exact pattern='/home' component={Home}/>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This is my Login/Home component (The Home component is the exact same just replacing Login):

```
// Dependencies
import React from 'react';

// Styles
import './login.scss';

class Login extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="content">
        <div className='title'>
            Login Page
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

I also noticed that when I navigate to `http://localhost:9999/home` I am getting this error also:

[image]

Something is apparently wired incorrectly, and I am a little confused by the documentation with the different versions existing.  And advice on how to get this fixed is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using `path` instead of  `pattern`?

Comment: That stopped the rendering of every page, still having the issue though when I navigate to /home, the home component isn't loading

Comment: You have to tell your server to always serve index, so your react app can take care of the routing.

Comment: When you say always server the index, would webpack take care of that when i do "start": "webpack-dev-server --port 9999" and the entry file is set to path.join(__dirname, 'src/index.jsx')?

Comment: try this: http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#the-historyapifallback-option , start it with `--history-api-fallback` flag

Comment: You are the real mvp, thank you for all of the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [React Training](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/path-string) :

> Routes without a path always match.

So in your case both will always match because u are using pattern.

Comment: That did stop the rendering as I mentioned to @Andrew Li

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Switch tag . It will switch between your components.

```
const App = () => { 
return ( <Router> 
          <Switch>  <Route exact path='/' component={Login}/> 
          <Route exact path='/home' component={Home}/> 
          </Switch> 
         </Router> ); };
```

Comment: Please add some context where switch tags needs to be added.